# Android studio removes my file/folder in packages (in android package) automatically, how to prevent?

Tags: android, android-studio, import, settings

I create a folder in android package path (in this path: app\build\generated\source\r\debug\android\ ) named "print" to put my files.
Application works well but after a while it removes automatically and must create and copy my files again.

I unchecked "Optimize imports on fly"  in Settings>Editor>General>AutoImport  but again deleted my file (same as checked).

I don't understand why it deletes that file and folder, You have any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the file inside the src folder ,not the build folder.

[screenShot showing where the file should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iNBH.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are putting your folder inside an Android generated folder. That will get regenerated every time you rebuild. You will have to put your files elsewhere. If they are media files, put them in a resource folder. Otherwise, assets works too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i must put them there, they are not media or any resource file to put them in asset, etc.

Comment: Assets can hold any files. You can't modify files that Android generates for permanent solutions.